# Hdfs file storage query

Tags: hadoop

When you want to store a file in hadoop, do you need the job tracker or task  tracker running in system?
Do they have any roles in file storing in hdfs?
Can you store a file in hdfs when these two services are down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When storing file in HDFS, jobtracker and tasktracker doesn't come into picture, jobtracker and tasktracker are processing demons while Namenode,datanode and secondary namenode is storage demons.

So you can store a file in HDFS when jobtracker and tasktracker is down.